# WCFs WebServiceHostFactory and timers

Tags: c#, ajax, wcf, json, service

I'm create AJAX Service with JSON and XML from [this example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-en/library/bb472488.aspx).
In service.cs I make changes :

```
    [ServiceContract(Namespace = "XmlAjaxService")]
        public interface ICalculator
        {
            ...

            [WebInvoke(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped)]
            int GetTimersCallCount();
        }

public class CalculatorService : ICalculator
    {
        private System.Timers.Timer timer = null;
        private int timerCalls = 0;

        public CalculatorService()
        {
            timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
            timer.Interval = 1000;
            timer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(timer_Elapsed);
            timer.Start();
        }

        public int GetTimersCallCount()
        {
            return this.timerCalls;
        }
}
```

On page javascript I do this:

```
function GetTimersTick() {

        // Create HTTP request
        var xmlHttp;
        try {
            xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } catch (e) {
            try {
                xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
            } catch (e) {
                try {
                    xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                } catch (e) {
                    alert("This sample only works in browsers with AJAX support");
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }

        // Create result handler
        xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("result").value = xmlHttp.responseText;
                document.getElementById("statustext").value = xmlHttp.getAllResponseHeaders();
            }
        }


        // Build the operation URL
            var url = "service.svc/";
            url = url + "GetTimersCallCount";
            xmlHttp.open("POST", url, true);
            xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
            xmlHttp.send();
    }
```

But When I press button with this function I'm get from service 0. What is wrong?

Comment: As far as I can tell from your example code, you never update `timerCalls`.

Comment: it's update I miss show this code here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that there is not one single instance of your `CalculatorService` class. It gets recreated on every new call to the service.

To enable single instance mode, use the following attribute on your service implementation class:

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single)]
public class CalculatorService : ICalculator { ... }
```

Be aware that when using single instance mode, you may need to synchronize calls to your service methods. In your specific example this isn't necessary since you are only reading and writing a 32 bit integer (which is an atomic operation).

Comment: Thank you Ronald for rigth question. And second in my service I want to get data from OPC and send it to clients? such in this example. I want to recieve data from OPC server every 1-5 second and store the data in IList<T>. And when client request my service methods return data IList<T> in Json or Xml. Thanks

Comment: If I don't update the page or don't send request after few minutes (10 or 15) if I send request service return 0. Where I change this time settings? Thanks.

Comment: I would not set up this kind of logic inside the service class but in a separate component. This component polls the OPC server every 5 seconds and stores the result in a database. The WCF service then reads from the database and sends the results to the client.

Comment: And how to control time of life this class created in first request?

Comment: I suppose you are running this from inside a web application (IIS)? You could use `Application_Start` for this.

Comment: Yes, this service hosted in IIS 7. This example http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-en/library/bb472488.aspx does not have ASMX file... In general I want to set the time which this class will not delete. I think that need to add attribute to CalculatorService class such as instance mode (you help above). Which attribute? Thanks.

Comment: There is no attribute that specifies how long a service stays alive. The point is that you should separate the service class and timer stuff.